# Creating/Changing table format using either estout or est table?

Tags: stata

I would like to produce a table which includes panel `panel bootstrapped standard errors` below the normal standard errors as well as the `significance level` at the end. I'm new to Stata and was able to produce the following structure:

```
est table RE REboot FE FEboot ,se stats(N)
```

where FEboot & REboot correspond to the `panel bootstrapped standard errors`. The desired output might look like:

```
            RE            FE

  Var1     1.109541     1.109541 
         (-.3294736)   (-.3294736)    
         ( boot se )   ( boot se )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `estout` and `matmap`, both from SSC (`ssc install <command>`):

```
sysuse auto, clear

// clear previously stored estimates        
estimates clear
eststo clear

// regression with bootstrap
eststo: regress price weight mpg, vce(bootstrap)

// compute non-bootstrap std errors
matrix evmodel = vecdiag(e(V_modelbased))
matmap evmodel evmodel, map(sqrt(@))

// add to stored results
estadd matrix evmodel

// VCV matrix (non-bootstrap)
matrix list e(V_modelbased)

// std error vector (non-bootstrap)
matrix list evmodel

// evmodel are non-bootstrap std errors; se are bootstrap std errors; 
estout *, cells(b(star fmt(3)) evmodel(par fmt(2)) se(par fmt(2)))
```

When Stata computes bootstrapped std errors, it saves both the bootstrapped and non-bootstrapped VCV matrices. You can compute the necessary std errors, add them to the collection of stored results, and finally, output to a table.